# Retrieve and insert into type objects in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, types, oracle10g

I have created an object type(address-city,state) in Oracle 10g .Then table cust_contact contains field of type address.Can anyone please provide SQL query to insert and retrieve values from this table including the type?

Answer (score 4):

Selection is easy.  Just include the type column in the query projection.  Assuming that the ADDRESS column is called contact_address:

```
select id, contact_name, contact_address
from cust_contact
/
```

With inserts you need to specify the type in the statement:

```
insert into cust_contact values
    (some_seq.nextval
     , 'MR KNOX'
     , address(34, 'Main Street', 'Whoville', 'SU')
    )
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "." syntax when retrieving columns:

select c.contact_address.city from cust_contact c;

Please note that if cust_contact is a table of objects, then you *must* use the table alias "c".

Answer (score 0):

for example :
first create type object say as address ,for this synatx or query is used:
create type address_ty as object(Street varchar2(50),City char(10),Zip number(6));

now use this address_ty as datatype in the time of table creation
for example:
create table Example(emp_name varchar2(10),emp_id number(10),address address_ty);
this will create table Example having 
Address as address_ty as a datatype..

Now insert into Values In Example Table
Insert Into example Values('Sandeep Kumar',595,address_ty('Snap on sector 126','Noida',201301);

tHANX....